# How to access private LinkedIn APIs solely for people search

Tags: linkedin-api

I am developing a business card app, and I want to be able to make a specific set of API calls to LinkedIn, mostly around search. I understand that previously the People Search API was a part of the v1 REST APIs [http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/people/people-search-api][1]

What level of access will I need to recreate the functionality of the People Search in the v2 API? The partner programs outline specific roles and what they enable developers to do. There's the Talent Solutions Partnership for Recruiters and Marketing Developer for Marketers etc. [https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply][2], but they do not cleanly overlap with my use case.

I want to add LinkedIn functionality to my app, which will allow our users to search and make connection requests. The user should be able to search for LinkedIn members using the name (first and last), company, and position. A lower priority function is for the user to be able to connect with another LinkedIn user through the app.

Will r_basicprofile member permission be enough for search?

Answer (score 0):

The api is deprecate but I don't know if it works yet.
[Deprecated info](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates)
But in the past it could be "Solutions Partnership for Recruiters"